# make menhir find all alternatives?

Tags: nlp, ocaml, ambiguous-grammar, menhir

I would like to change the behavior of menhir's output in follwoing way:
I want it to look up **all** grammatical alternatives if it finds any, and put them in a list and get me back this ambigouus interpretation. It shall not reduce conflicts, just store them.

In the source code of menhir, it seems to me, that I have to look in "Engine.ml". The resultant syntactically determined token comes in a variant type item "Accepted v" as a state of a checkpoint of the grammatical automaton. This content is found by a function "accept env prod" before, that is part of a bundle of recursive functions, that change the states.

Do you have a tip, how I could change these functions to put all the possible results in the list here and proceed as if nothing happened? Or do you think, that this wont work anyway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [GLR parser generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLR_parser) (G is for generalized). Menhir is not such tool, and I doubt you could modify it easily to do what you want.

However, there is another tool that does exactly what you want: [dypgen](http://dypgen.free.fr/).